# Is it possible to configure javac version in maven compiler plugin without installing that specific Jdk version?

Tags: java, maven

How maven Identify the JavaC loacation without installing that particular version?
For Example:my machine Have JDK 1.6 and didn't install JDK1.7 and set the configuration in pom.xml like mentioned below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Will it work  without installing JDK1.7 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will if you install a later version. You need a JDK of at least version Java 7.

A down side for using a newer JDK is that the javac is not smart enough to prevent you using methods or class which were added after the version you specify. i.e. it ignores the `@since`

E.g. Stream is added in Java 8, but if you specify `1.7` it will still let you use it.

BTW You can get Java 8 update 5, and Java 9 EA.

Comment: You can use the Animal-Sniffer-Plugin(http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) for making sure that you do not use too "new" methods.